# ErrorReportValve in cas embedded tomcat

Tags: tomcat, cas

We are using apereo cas in our project.  We have an security issue in which tomcat version should be hidden in error pages.

I found that ErrorReportValve tomcat config should be added for hiding tomcat version in error pages.

Apereo CAS is having embedded tomcat.  I dont find any property in CAS to add this value.

Can anyone please help in adding ErrorReportValve in apereo cas embedded tomcat.

Thanks
Senthil